# Can a meteor streak exhibit different colors denoting presence of more than1 element?

Tags: observational-astronomy, amateur-observing, meteor, meteoroid

A meteoroid's elemental composition can be determined by the color it exhibits while burning in the earth's atmosphere which we also call a "meteor". However, is it possible that a meteor streak can exhibit more than 1 color as seen in the attached image? (Image Credits to respective owner)

Are the blue, pinkish-red, cyan, and green colors denoting different elemental compositions of the meteoroid or is it because of the camera lens that clicked this meteor streak in long-exposure?

[image: Meteor streak with more than 1 color]

Comment: If I am not mistaken, most of the light we see from meteors is our own atmosphere, made so hot by the shock wave that it ionizes and glows. Elements from the meteor [can certainly add color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteoroid#Colours), or at least additional spectral lines, but the primary source of light is the ionized air itself, not the meteor (which does not "burn"). See also in Earthscience SE [Have "frosty meteorites" ever been observed soon after landing? Are there photos?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/21197/6031) and the comments below it.